# Copy a list of files from one directory to another - How to put text file into array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, file-io

Longtime lurker, first time posting! I'm new to Ruby so I would love some help on this.

I have a large text file with a list of files separated by a break, so it looks like this:

```
ARO_9501.jpg
ARO_9506.jpg
IMG_1499.jpg
IMG_1511.jpg
```

How can I get this text file into an array so I can call .each on it and copy the files to another directory?

Answer (score 0):

You can go this way also using [**`IO::readlines`**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-c-readlines) :

```
ar = File.open("/home/kirti/ruby/foo.txt","r") do |fil|
    fil.readlines.map(&:strip)
end
p ar
# >> ["ARO_9501.jpg", "ARO_9506.jpg", "IMG_1499.jpg", "IMG_1511.jpg"]
```

As per the @steenslag comments:

```
ar = File.readlines("/home/kirti/ruby/foo.txt").map(&:chomp)
ar # => [ "ARO_9501.jpg", "ARO_9506.jpg", "IMG_1499.jpg", "IMG_1511.jpg"]
```

Comment: `readlines`already gives you an array (and `map` gives you another); no need to splat the array and push the values in a third array. `ar = File.readlines("/home/kirti/ruby/foo.txt").map(&:chomp)`

Comment: @steenslag I was looking for this.. But couldn't remember,when I was writing my previous code.. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: When using File.readlines what is the name of the array it's mapping them into? That line of code works but I'm not sure what it's saving the filenames to?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I generally do:

```
fileNameArray = File.read("/path/to/file.txt").split("\n")
```

Or, if you just need to iterate over the file names and don't necessarily need an array containing the names (it looks like you don't), I usually use this:

```
File.read("/path/to/file.txt").each_line do |line|
  # do operations using line
end
```

Docs:
[`IO::read`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-c-read) (`File` extends `IO`)
      [`String`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html) `.split()` and `each_line()`